# add advgrid selected row to cxmemo1

Tags: delphi, datagrid

When I select and delete a row in AdvStringGrid I am trying to add the deleted row to a cxmemo.

```
cxMemo1.Lines.Add('deleted :' +(AdvStringGrid1.SelectedRow));
```

I am getting :
[dcc32 Error] Alarm.pas(230): E2029 '[' expected but ')' found

Even if I change the bracket still it does not work.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? I believe `SelectedRow` is an indexed property. If so, syntax is `SelectedRow[Index]`. If I understand correctly it returns `Integer`, the index of the selected row(s). So this might not be what you want.

Comment: I dont think string grid has indexes

Comment: Well I'm not sure I understand what you mean. The `Index` would be the selected row you want to refer to.

Comment: I agree with @nil. Why not just rtfm?  In any case, since you are apparently trying to record a deleted row, shouldn't you be saving the row's contents *before* you delete it?

Comment: yep.. But what index? Doing :cxMemo1.Lines.Add('deleted :'+ inttostr(AdvStringGrid1.SelectedRow[0])); Gives me : deleted :1

Comment: I really don't mean that snarky or offensive, you really should read the documentation. Working with complex third-party components just by trial and error without having a grasp of how they are designed leads to a) frustration and b) errors that wait to happen at a much later time. Been there, done that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you have selected multiple rows, you can use

> AdvStringGrid1.SelectedRow[i]

to get the actual index of the selected row. In that case 'i' is the index of the row in the selection, NOT the actual index.

What you need is the property

> AdvStringGrid1.Row

, which gives you the actual index of the selected row (Not in a Multiple selection).